# I am a beginner in coding with Python, I want to know why Python is not printing the content of my file in the terminal

Tags: file, terminal, python-3.11

```
with open("bruh.txt") as file:  

    print(file.read())
    print(file.closed)
```

Output:

```
PS C:\\Users\\hp\\Desktop\\sss\> & C:/Users/hp/AppData/Local/Mi crosoft/WindowsApps/python3.11.exe c:/Users/hp/Desktop/sss/file.py

True

PS C:\\Users\\hp\\Desktop\\sss\>
```

The file is in the same folder so I don't need to list the path, I saw a video on Youtube, he wrote the same code and the content of his file was printed in the terminal

The name of the file was verified; then the path was listed. I googled the problem, but the results did not help. They assumed the file did not exist, but it did

Comment: Hi, do you have content in the file bruh.txt ? (We never know :) )

Comment: Please format your question title and description. It's incredibly hard to understand it

Comment: yes,There is content in the file. It is difficult for me to explain my problem, but there are only a few things I can say: the file content doesn't appear on the terminal; there is no error, there is a text in the file that should be printed  when i run the code,  thanks in advance